# Shorter way to write NSPredicate format string for testing multiple properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nspredicate

Is there a shorter way to write the format string for a predicate equivalent to this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"key1 CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR key2 CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR key3 CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchString, searchString, searchString];
```

I have written a few predicate format strings like this, and I was thinking to simplify that by writing a method that takes an array of key paths and the search string to construct such a predicate. But I thought I’d ask if there is a built-in way to do this, before doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSCompoundPredicate` is a subclass of `NSPredicate` and takes an `NSArray` of `NSPredicate` instances. However, this would mean that you still have to construct the `NSPredicate` objects (the subpredicates if you will) yourself. My suggestion is to write your own method (as you are planning to) but use `NSCompoundPredicate` as it is designed for this purpose.

```
- (NSPredicate *)predicateWithKeyPaths:(NSArray *)keyPaths andSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *keyPath in keyPaths) {
    NSPredicate *subpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", keyPath, searchTerm];
    [subpredicates addObject:subpredicate];
}

NSPredicate *result = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];
[subpredicates release];

return result;}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is about the method I would have written. I was just hoping that this was built-in somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a shorter way. An alternative is to use `NSCompoundPredicate`'s `orPredicateWithSubpredicates:` method. That's hardly shorter, but probably not as "boring" as having to concatenate strings.