# NSPredicate with multiple comparisons for one query string

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I was wondering if there is a way to simplify an NSPredicate that takes in a single query string for multiple comparison targets. I'm searching multiple attributes of a core data entity for the same query string. My current query looks something like this...

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attributeA contains[cd] %@) OR (attributeB contains[cd] %@) OR (attributeC contains[cd] %@)", searchString, searchString, searchString];
```

Note that this works perfectly, but it does look a bit unsightly. Especially the `searchString, searchString, searchString` part. Any tips on how I could possibly simplify this would be great!

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSCompoundPredicate for your OR & AND operations like this.

**Obj-C  - OR**

```
// OR Condition //

NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Obj-C  - AND**

```
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 1"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"X == 2"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2]];
```

**Swift - OR**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift - AND**

```
let predicate1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
let predicate2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
let predicate:NSPredicate  = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2] )
```

**Swift 3 - OR**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

**Swift 3 - AND**

```
    let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "X == 1")
    let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "Y == 2")
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .and, subpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2])
```

Comment: Including both Objective-C and Swift code improves the quality of this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attributeA contains[cd] $A OR attributeB contains[cd] $A or attributeC contains[cd] $A"];
NSDictionary *sub = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:searchString forKey:@"A"];
p = [p predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:sub];
```

Or you could do something weirder, like this:

```
- (NSPredicate *)buildOrPredicate:(NSDictionary *)stuff {
  NSMutableArray *subs = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSString *key in stuff) {
    NSString *value = [stuff objectForKey:stuff];
    NSPredicate *sub = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", key, value];
    [subs addObject:sub];
  }
  return [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subs];
}
```

And then invoke that with:

```
NSDictionary *stuff = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       searchString, @"attributeA",
                       searchString, @"attributeB",
                       searchString, @"attributeC",
                       nil];
NSPredicate *p = [self buildOrPredicate:stuff];
```

---

The only other thing I can think of that might work is to try using positional specifies in the predicate format. However, I don't know if the parser recognizes them the same way that `+stringWithFormat:` does:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"attributeA contains[cd] %1$@ OR attributeB contains[cd] %1$@ or attributeC contains[cd] %1$@", searchString];
```

Comment: Thanks, but all 3 of those are longer. I have no issues with using shorthand, even if it may be tough to read. I was looking for a solution that is both short and eliminates the need for having "searchString" in there 3 times (if it's possible)!

Comment: Nope, the parser doesn't seem to understand positional specifiers. :( BTW I found a dup of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305940/shorter-way-to-write-nspredicate-format-string-for-testing-multiple-properties Similar answers there.