# NSPredicate unable to parse format string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I can't see any problem with these line of code. Why can't it parse?

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username  CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || "
                                  "(userId    CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || "
                                  "(firstname CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || "
                                  "(lastname  CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)", searchString]"
```

The Log doesn't help either.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format
>   string "(username CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || (userId CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) ||
>   (firstname CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || (lastname CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)"'

**Edit 1:**

Okay, it seems like predicateWithFormat doesn't understand "%1$@". I switch it to

```
[... predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:...]] // (same format as above)
```

It passed the line. But, the next problem is:

```
self.filteredUserList = [self.userList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity User is
>   not key value coding-compliant for the key "a".'

"a" is the keyword I entered in the searchTextBox. WUT?

I printed out the predicate in the debug console, looks nothing wrong:

```
username CONTAINS[cd] a OR userId CONTAINS[cd] a OR firstname CONTAINS[cd] a OR lastname CONTAINS[cd] a
```

**Edit 2:**

Okay, problem solved with this super ugly code:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username  CONTAINS[cd] %@) || "
                                  "(userId    CONTAINS[cd] %@) || "
                                  "(firstname CONTAINS[cd] %@) || "
                                  "(lastname  CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchString, searchString, searchString, searchString];
```

What if I want to expand the search field in the future? I've got to add more parameters? more ", searchString, searchString, searchString"?

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Ewan and Bannings, giving 2 options to my question. I tested both of them, and they worked liek a charm. Can someone explain the different between those two, and in which case should I use which option?

** NOTE **

Bannings' answer is alright, until my search string contains a single quote `'`, then the app crash. So I think use Ewan's one is better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username CONTAINS[cd] $str) || ..."] predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:@{@"str": searchString}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try change `%1$@` to `'%1$@'`:

```
NSString *formatString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(username CONTAINS[cd] '%1$@') || (userId CONTAINS[cd] '%1$@') || (firstname CONTAINS[cd] '%1$@') || (lastname CONTAINS[cd] '%1$@')", searchString];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formatString];
```

Comment: Awwwright! That works too. But I just accepted Ewan's answer. So sorry.

Comment: Best answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the string for each variable, if you use 5 %@ you need to apply either the same searchString value or another value filling for that %@

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(username CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) ||
(userId CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) || (firstname CONTAINS[cd] %1$@) ||
(lastname CONTAINS[cd] %1$@)", searchString1,searchString2,searchString3,searchString4]
```

Comment: I kinda know that. Is there any way around? Because all my searchString is the same value...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536750/nspredicate-with-multiple-comparisons-for-one-query-string Check this out...

Comment: I don't want to use compound predicate, since my predicate is not too complex.